# Ffmpeg video player does not appear in my applications overview. A search for it turns up no results. Snap'd store shows it installed. Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Ffmpeg version n4.0. Had similar issue with movian video player, however, icon did appear in application overview. Clicking on icon resulted in no visible result.

Comment: ffmpeg is a command line tool. Have you tried running it from a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is a command-line ffmpeg tool itself, designed for processing of video and audio files.

Answer (score 0):

You cab check the version and its location from the Terminal.

For example on my 22.04.1 system, in terminal type:

```
which ffmpeg
```

the result is:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Also `ffmpeg --version` will provide further data about your installed version.